# Transform a dictionary into a list of tuples with Python

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I want to transform a dictionary into a list of tuples, but doing it 'row-wise': the first tuple should cointain the first values, the second tuple the second values, and so on.

I have some working code, but I wonder if there is a more idiomatic way of doing it because my solution seems too verbose.

```
data = {
    'a': [1,2,3,4],
    'b': [1,2,3,5],
    'c': [1,2,3,6]
}

tuple_list = []
for i, x in enumerate(data['a']):
    tpl = []
    for key in data:
        val = data[key][i]
        tpl.append(val)
    tuple_list.append(tuple(tpl))
```

**output**

```
[(1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) which *iterate over several iterables in parallel, producing tuples with an item from each one*.

```
print(list(zip(*data.values())))
# Equivalent to 
# print(list(zip([1, 2, 3, 4], [1,2,3,5], [1, 2, 3, 6])))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the following one-liner:

```
list(zip(*data.values()))
```

Explanation: `data.values()` gives you a list dictionary values (in this case, lists). Next we use `*` operator to unpack that list into three separate arguments for `zip` function. `zip` takes several iterables as arguments, and creates tuples from respective elements of each iterable. Then we just have to convert it from zip object to a list (if you're gonna do any further processing, it might be possible to keep it as zip object).